# Buttons doesn't work when building for android - Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a main menu inside my unity game and for some reason when i build the game for android to run it on my phone the buttons does not work, but it's not disabled.

**My scene objects:**

[image]

**My event system object:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Three things I can suggest:

First, make sure that on your button object, raycast target is deselected. At times, this is destabilizing the text of the button, hence making the button itself invalid.

Second, check to see if the EventSystem is working. From what I'm seeing on your screen, you might have disabled it or accidentally deleted its script while working on the scene objects. You can re-create it if necessary through GameObject>UI>EventSystem.

If these don't work, you can try the steps shown here:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1115464/ispointerovergameobject-not-working-with-touch-inp.html

This is directly related to button objects not working with touch input devices. Hope this helps!